# Make cursor jump X lines up or down with keyboard shortcut - Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm coming from the Atom text editor, and I loved the [line-jumper](https://atom.io/packages/line-jumper) plugin.

The closest thing I've found in the Intellij plugin list (which isn't what I want) is [AceJump](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086-acejump).

Is there anything I can do that accomplishes the functionality of `line-jumper` for the Atom plugin listed?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to create a macro and assign it to a key combination that is not used. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686376/how-can-i-navigate-lines-of-files-with-the-keyboard-quicker-in-intellij) for information on how to create and assign custom macros.

Comment: The macro I made goes up for down X times, but it doesn't just JUMP straight to the Xth line, so it feels kinda studdery. Is that expected since it's just performing the steps I added?